# Links do not work when a three-column footer is converted to an one-column footer

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem with my website. ([www.cemf.ir](http://www.cemf.ir)). The footer has three columns and everything works fine (links are clickable) when it has three columns. However, when I resize the browser and the width gets smaller, the number of columns in the footer becomes one and only the links in the last part of the footer works. I guess there is something wrong with .column-wrapper class in the css  when the screen width gets smaller. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the float of the last column wrapper should work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.site-footer.three-col .column-wrapper:last-child {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked on desktop version. But in mobile version I still have the same problem.

Comment: @user3672271 sorry, I just tested on the chrome dev tool based on the device width and I thought it works.

Comment: That is a progress. Your solution worked for desktop version. So, I'll keep it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason whose cause I can't find out, the very last `.column-wrapper` in the footer covers (although transparent) almost the whole screen on mobiles, including most the other footer elements, and also doesn't let any mouseclicks through.

In the browser code inspector adding the following CSS setting made the links in the other footer elements clickable:

```
#recent-posts-5 {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This made the first column clickable, but the next two columns are still non-clickable. In chrome on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a good solution for it. I used z-index property as you see below:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)

.column-wrapper:last-child {
      z-index: 1000;
  }

  .column-wrapper:nth-child(2) {
      z-index: 1001;
  }

  .column-wrapper:first-child {
      z-index: 1002;
  }
```

z-index put columns layer on layer and the problem of the last column-wrapper was solved, since it is now under all the columns in the footer.